# Getting file name when one is selected

Tags: php, html

I've created a popup from which you can select a file to upload, that has the following structure:

```
<div id = 'upload_container'>
    <span id = "close_btn">X</span>
    <!--Content-->
    <input type = 'file' id = 'upload_hidden' name = 'file_to_upload'>
    <p id = 'upload_container_text'>Choose a file to upload</p>
    <p id = 'file_name'><?php echo $file_name ?></p>
    <!-- // -->
</div>
```

The way i trigger the window to select a file is by clicking the *"Choose a file to upload"* that will trigger the click event on the file input which is hidden.

The thing i want to do now is to display the file name that was chosen, on the paragraph with the id *'file_name'* .
What i tried is:

```
$file_name = "";
if(isset($_FILES['file_to_upload'])){
    $file_name = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'];
}
```

and to the paragraph i added:

```
<p id = 'file_name'><?php echo $file_name ?></p>
```

but nothing happens. Any ideas ?

**Thank you.**

Comment: Use client side for this. AKA javascript

Comment: Do a print_r($_FILES) to see what that contains, just in case your activating page is not actually sending that to php. Then also check if your "form" tag has the appropriate file enctype: enctype='multipart/form-data'

Comment: "Use client side for this. AKA javascript" - I'm assuming theres an actual need to upload the file to the server for this, and what we are seeing is just the part of the problem asked. Hopefully the file isn't being uploaded just to output the filename?

Comment: @Randall You're correct. This was only the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the file name of the file selected for upload,  use javascript.  Attach an onchange listener on the file I input and then get the file name and output to the paragraph.

```
<input type='file' id='file' onchange='getFileData(this)'/>

<script>
function getFileData(object){
var file = object.files[0];
var name = file.name;//you can set the name to the paragraph id 
document.getElementById('file_name').value=name;//set name using core javascript

}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. This was really helpful.

Comment: My pleasure friend :)

Answer (score 1):

For trigger an input file was hidden, you can call with this code :

```
$('#upload_container_text').click(function(){
  $('#upload_hidden').trigger('click');
}
```

For get your file name via client side, you can try with it :

```
$('#upload_hidden').change(function(){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e){
    $('#filename').text(e.name); // or you can pass this.files[0];
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  $(this).val(reader);
});
```

For get your file name via server side :

1. You can pass a file name with form and atribute action to your url
2. Get file name with $_GET['you file']
3. Echo $_GET['your file'] in p with id file name
   });

Comment: Your wellcome .